# FunctionType: why constructed function differs from original?

Tags: python, function, cpython

Say I have a simple function like:

```
>>> def something(value):
...     return value + 2
```

so, using `types.FunctionType` I can build its copy:

```
>>> new_function = FunctionType(something.__code__, something.__globals__)
```

Turns out that these functions differs one from another:

```
>>>new_function == something
False
```

Situations like that one are kind of acceptable - who knows right? Except that this two objects are identical byte to byte (memory dump for func `something` attached below):

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 114, 163, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 224, 65, 53, 62, 56, 127, 0, 0, 72, 103, 162, 63, 56, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 0, 164, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 94, 53, 62, 56, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 112, 248, 156, 63, 56, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 94, 53, 62, 56, 127, 0, 0]
```

Have a look at cpython source for `PyFunctionObject`:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/funcobject.h#L21
I have actually found the last field `__qualname__` location inside a memory dump:

```
>>> [int(value) for value in struct.pack("Q", id(something.__qualname__))]
[48, 94, 53, 62, 56, 127, 0, 0]
```

As you can see the address of `__qualname__` string is actully the last thing inside a dump, as expected.

The question: this two objects are the same and since `PyFunction_Type` does not implement any custom rich-comparators it uses default struct-to-struct comparation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L671
How this two instances can differ?

**UPDATE**:
My bad, default compare function compares two **POINTERS** to structs, not structs. So event though structs are the same comparator yields False.

Comment: The simple answer is that when you instantiate `new_function` Python isn't assigning it the same [integer identity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id), compare `id(something)` and `id(new_function)`. If you shallow copy by `new_function = something` they'll have the same identity.

Comment: Sure, but comparation of two instances is not the same as comparation of identities.

Comment: Is "the equality check is done by identity" an acceptable answer to the question then?

Comment: Does `==` operator for C structs performs comparation by value?

Comment: You don't have structs there, you have pointers. Those are compared and they are obviously not pointing to the same `PyObject`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, my bad.

Comment: No, function objects do not implement rich comparisons. Why would they?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I checked that just in case.